# Can #define process arithmetic operations in preprocessing?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

Can the C macro `#define` process arithmetic operations in preprocessing?

For example, if I write

```
#define A 1 + 1
```

will it be pre-processed to be equivalent to

```
#define A 2
```

before compiling?

Furthermore, is it possible to define constants this way without computation overhead:

```
#define A 1
#define B A + 1
#define C B + 1
...
```

?

Comment: There's no need to do that, because any decent compiler will deal with such pure functions and propagate constants through them, and they will have no runtime cost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Macros are text replacements (token replacements to be more accurate).

```
#define A 1 + 1
int main() { printf("%d\n", A); }
```

will expand to  (run `gcc -E` on the source to get the preprocessor expansion)

```
int main() { printf("%d\n", 1 + 1); }
```

(which BTW, is why it's wise to heavily parenthesize in macros (`#define A (1+1)`), because
 you'll usually want `A*3` to then be `6` ( `(1+1)*3` ) not 4   ( `1+1*3`) ) ).

And yes `1+1`, seeing as it satisfies the standard's rules for integer constant expressions,  is pretty much guaranteed to be processed at compile time and so you can use it in contexts where  an integer constant expression is required.

E.g.:

```
 #define A (1+1)
 extern char  array[A] = { [A-1]='c' } ; //ICE required
 struct s { int bitfield:A; }; //ICE required
 enum { a = A }; //ICE required
 int x = A; //ICE required
 int main ()
 {
    switch(1) case A: puts("unreachable"); //ICE required
 }
```